# How to get data from an array inside an object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying get data from array so that look like this:

> [Rome, Milan, Barselona, Madrid]

and my brain seems like go to blackout... How can i do this?

```
const countries = {
        italy: {
            id: 1,
            cities: ["Rome", "Milan"],
        },
        spain: {
            id: 2,
            cities: ["Barselona", "Madrid"],
        }
    };

    function getCitiesDates(data) {
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
function getCitiesDates(data) {
  return Object.values(data).flatMap(({ cities = [] }) => cities);
}

const countries = {
  italy: { id: 1, cities: ["Rome", "Milan"] },
  spain: { id: 2, cities: ["Barselona", "Madrid"] }
};
console.log( getCitiesDates(countries) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it in one line with `Object.keys(data).flatMap(c => data[c].cities);`

```js
const countries = {
  italy: {
    id: 1,
    cities: ["Rome", "Milan"],
  },
  spain: {
    id: 2,
    cities: ["Barselona", "Madrid"],
  }
};

function getCitiesDates(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).flatMap(c => data[c].cities);
}
console.log(getCitiesDates(countries))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it could be to use Object.Keys(), loop the Keys and then map the cities.

Something like this:

```
const keys = Object.Keys(countries);
const cities = keys.flatMap(key => countries[key].cities)

console.log(cities) // [Rome, Milan, Barselona, Madrid]
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` (not Keys()).